# IE 8 "Find on this page" Feature is very slow

Tags: internet-explorer-8, find

I've tried to find a work around for this, but most of my searches end up in people who can't use the find-on-this-page feature at all in IE8.  It appears for me, but for some reason takes forever to find things on a text heavy page, often making IE completely un-usable for several minutes.

I thought I was the only one, but other people in my office have noticed it as well.

Is anyone aware of a work around?

---

EDIT:
Well don't I feel dumb.  I finally figured out a fix for this.  For our company website (and I'm sure many others that are heavy with heavy filters) you have to have to always run with compatibility view on for find to not lag.

Comment: A severe performance issue like that should be considered a bug in IE, and I suggest you report it to Microsoft - preferably figure out the simplest web page which will produce the same behavior so they can more easily reproduce and debug it.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to try a different browser such as [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/firefox.html), [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/), [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/), or [Opera](http://www.opera.com/)

However this isn't an option for every site. So you might have better luck using the IE rendering engine in a different browser frame work via [IE Tab](http://www.google.com/search?&q=ie+tab) for [FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en)

Comment: Our users aren't allowed to use anything except for IE, and for purposes related to session issues in our web app they've all been upgraded to IE8.

Comment: IE tab would still allow you to use the IE8 engine in a different browser framework, one with a slightly better text search engine.

Comment: Yeah but from the links you sent, they would still have to have Firefox or Chrome installed on their machines.  I am not authorized to do this.  There are company wide rules forbidding anyone outside of IT to have anything other than IE.  
The IE Tab will be helpful to our developers and myself though, so thanks for your help. :)

Comment: ah, I see. I'm sorry to hear that.